# Запустить пересчет размеров ячеек для NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Имеется класс ViewController, наследующийся от NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate. Каждая из ячеек может свой размер. Реализованы такие функции, как

```
numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView)
tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int)
tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int)
tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
tableViewColumnDidResize(notification: NSNotification)
```

Возможно ли при изменении размеров контрола (вызове функции tableViewColumnDidResize) принудительно пересчитать размеры каждой из ячеек?
Возможное решение, `TableView.reloadData()` не подходит по прочине тормозов, т.к. происходит перезапрос информации.

Comment: так вынесите запрос информации из reload

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Предлагаете реализовывать отдельно reload, с возможностью полный перезагрузки информации, и вариант только с просчетом размеров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, все решается проще. `TableView` имеет функцию `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged`. Ищем все видимые строки через `TableView.rowsInRect(self.scrollView.contentView.bounds)`и отдаем их в ту функцию.

```
func tableViewColumnDidResize(notification: NSNotification) {
  let visibleRows: NSRange = self.messageTableView.rowsInRect(self.scrollView.contentView.bounds)
  messageTableView.noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: visibleRows))
}
```